# How to reject an invalid string for userinput in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I need help with rejecting an invalid string in JS:

I want to ensure any input other than the numbers 1-6 is rejected e.g 0 or 7+ or any other character, here is what i got so far

```js
function getGraph() {
  var i;
  var results = [];
  var dicePoss = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
  var tracker;

  for (i = 1; i <= 30; i++) {
    tracker = parseInt(results.push(prompt("Enter your numbers", 'diceroll')));

  }

  if (tracker <= 6 && tracker > 0) {
    document.getElementById('x-axis').innerHTML = tracker;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('reject').innerHTML = "Please enter a numberPlease enter a valid number between 1-6";
  }

  document.getElementById('y-axis').innerHTML = dicePoss;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<body>

  <p id="y-axis">Frequency of die rolls(results)</p>
  <p id="x-axis">Dice Possible Rolls between 1-6</p>
  <p id="reject"></p>

  <input type="button" value="Graph Column Chat for Dice Roll" onclick="getGraph();">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please write a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It's not nice to make someone trying your snippet go through 30 popups just to test your code.

Answer (score 2):

To fix the issue you can use regular expressions:

```
var str = prompt("Enter your numbers",'diceroll');

if (str.match(/^[1-6]$/)) {
   results.push(str);
} else {
   // show error
}
```

And some comment about your code, you have this:

```
for (i = 1; i <= 30; i++) {
    tracker = parseInt(results.push(prompt("Enter your numbers", 'diceroll')));

}
```

which is wrong in two ways:

- first it will parse result of push which is index (number) of last pushed value.
- and second is that the value will be last push (tracker === 30).

In my code the check goes inside the loop, not outside of it.